# Can't share variables between pipelines in Gitlab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, gitlab-api

I already tryed a lot of different variant and nothing wording for me.

This is example code of gitlab.ci project:

```
cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG

publish_image:
  stage: publish-image
  only: [ dev ]
  variables: 
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  script:
    - echo "IMAGE_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/data.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/data.txt

retag_image_stg:
  stage: retag-image-stg
  only: [ stg ]
  script:
    - echo $IMAGE_TAG
    - ls -lah
    - pwd
    - cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/data.txt
    - cat data.txt
```

**Cache** and **Artifacts** not accessible in the next pipeline.

**API** can't use - I can download artifact if I indicate the project and job id, but this variables every time changed, so to get artifact from first pipe I need first to share variables with IDs that impossible.

Only suggestion in my mind is somehow to use different branch in GIT to store artifacts and retrieve them.

Comment: If you read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts it explains these are job artifacts. A job artifact when created is available to other jobs in the same piepieline. Not in other pipelines. Same woth variables of jobs. They don't carry over to other jobs or pipelines. You can use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv to communicate vars between jobs but again not between pipelines

Answer (score 1):

I found 3 solutions to share variables between pipelines in Gitlab:

1. Use some branch in your git to store this variables.

   - git clone -b artifacts-branch --single-branch https://$GIT_USER:$GIT_TOKEN@your-gitlab.git
   - cd in your git folder
   - echo "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" > image_tag
   - git add image_tag
   - git config --global user.email "your mail"
   - git config --global user.name "your name"
   - git commit -m "message"
   - git push
2. Use API calls to PUSH and PULL variables in Gitlab

   - 'curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: token" --data "value=123" "https://your.gitlab-site.com/api/v4/projects/projectID/variables/TEST_ENV"'
   - 'curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: token" "https://your.gitlab-site.com/api/v4/projects/projectID/variables/TEST_ENV" | jq -r '.value''
3. Or use shell executor for gitlab runner to store values in files directly on the server.